# Not able to run... Errors

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

After running "Run Custom Tool" on the .tt dropped on my VS2k8 prj I'm not able to run my program.. shows 8 errors like:

Error   23  The type 'SouthWind.LanguageText' already contains a definition for 'KeyName'   C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Meus documentos\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication4\WindowsFormsApplication4\ActiveRecord.cs   41320   23  WindowsFormsApplication4

Error   30  Ambiguity between 'SouthWind.LanguageText.KeyName()' and 'SouthWind.LanguageText.KeyName'   C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Meus documentos\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication4\WindowsFormsApplication4\ActiveRecord.cs   41243   25  WindowsFormsApplication4
...
... and others

Any problem on my DB? Can you help me? Using MS SQL 2008

I'd also like to know if there's a need to create a new table/column, should the .tts runs again to update the classes?

I'm a OR/M newbie! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

KeyName is the name of a method in the IActiveRecord interface so this is probably conflicting with the name of a column in your LanguageText table. If you rename the column then you should be OK.
Once you're renamed the column you will need to run the .tt files again for your changes to be picked up.